# Unexplained delay between ad onAdClosed and finish

Tags: delay, activity-finish

After clicking back button, dialog is opened asking if user want to save his work before returning to menu activity (finishing current activity).
If there is ad loaded, it will show and the activity is finished on onAdClosed.

But there is unexplained delay between closing ad and returning to the menu. If the ad is displayed for some time, the delay disappear. When the ad is not loaded so it will not be shown, finishing is smooth too.

```
mInterstitialBack.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

---

```
 builderSingle.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.noSave),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if (mInterstitialBack.isLoaded()) {
                                mInterstitialBack.show();
                            } else {
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: original post edited